# scrollview content returns to original position when textfield resigns first responder

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

New iOS developer with first commissioned app.

Have scrollview with multiple text fields.

Have coded upward movement of page content in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` so that text fields are not obscured by keyboard. Have coded keyboard to disappear when keyboard return key pressed using `textFieldShouldReturn:` and I have coded for the screen to return to its original position in `didHideKeyboard`.

if a user taps outside of the first responder text field (including if they tap in another text field) somehow the screen returns to its original position without any of my code being fired, and without the keyboard disappearing. I am not using `autolayout`.

My question is how can I prevent the screen from returning to its original position when a user taps a second text field immediately after typing in the first text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do when the user tries to touch outside the text field. One option would be to simply disable scrolling on the scroll view while the text field is editing, and then re-enabling it upon dismissal of the keyboard.

A different option would be to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate method `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` to detect the user is moving the scroll view, and then reseting the scrollview's offset, and resigning first responder from the text field from there.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (myTextField.isFirstResponder) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:originalOffset];
        [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried disabling user interaction in both didShowKeyboard and textFieldDidBeginEditing using the code: scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = false; This resulted in no keyboard appearing, and no interaction with any text field, although i could still page through the scrollview. A confusing result. Did i misunderstand you? I tried your second suggestion, but it made no difference.

Comment: YES! That did it. Thankyou so much 0x7ffffff. I did misread your original suggestion which was right first time.

Answer (score 0):

For Your issue, You can get batter library named `TPKeyboardAvoiding` to set scroll position with `UITextField` and `UITextView` with keyboard open and hide. You dont need any manual setting of scroll postion in diffrent methods.
 It is subclass of `UIScrollView`. And its manage all stuff.
 Please get files and implementation details on [Keyboard Avoiding Scrollview](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)